# R Shiny DT change cell colour based on string pattern

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have a DT data table which contain strings like below:
[image]

I want to change the colour of the cell, so that the cells with strings that contain "OK" will turn green, and cells with strings that contain "ERROR" will turn red. I know that I can change the cell colour by using `formatStyle` and `styleEqual` but it does not seem to work when matching string patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(DT)

render <- c(
  "function(data, type, row){",
  "  if(type === 'display'){",
  "    var color = /OK$/.test(data) ? 'green' : (/ERROR$/.test(data) ? 'red' : 'black');",
  "    data = '<span style=\"color: ' + color + ';\">' + data + '</span>';",
  "  }",
  "  return data;",
  "}"
)

dat <- data.frame(
  a = c("1 - OK", "1 - ERROR", "2 - ERROR"), 
  b = c("3 - ERROR", "2 - OK", "3 - OK")
)

datatable(
  dat, 
  options = list(
    columnDefs = list(
      list(targets = c(1, 2), render = JS(render))
    )
  )
)
```

[image]